# new version for the classes I've use in my application

Tags: php, class

2 months ago I was writing a web-application which use some classes to draw some charts. I've modified little those classes in order to fit with my needs. Now I wish to use a new(and official) version of that class, but also to have my modifications available.

The problem is that I don't remember exactly all the modification I've made and I don't wana loose them when I use the new version of the classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just compare those files with a text diff tool that in included in many programs. If you're on Windows, you will find diff tools in Total Commander, PSPad, TortoiseSVN and many others.

My favourite diff tool is that in TortoiseSVN. It works also for files that are not in any repository.

Answer (score 1):

That's really unfortunate. What's your question?

Have you been using version control, because if you had, you could go back to the earliest version of the classes and compare all of your modifications.

Comment: And this is why even for the smallest, simplest projects, you should use source control...

Answer (score 0):

It should be easy to pick out methods you've created. Look at the new methods available in the new class, compared to the methods available in the old class, and you'll find your methods.

You could strip out your methods, and then compare both of the classes side-by-side after that. Or, the developers working on the classes may have distributed a changelog to let you know what has changed between the two versions.

Answer (score 0):

There are many comparision programs for that purpose, try with one of them.